# Setting up approval workflow in SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2007

I am trying to setup Approval workflow in SharePoint Designer 2007:

1. User creates a new list item
2. Should trigger an email and assign the task to manager
3. Manager reviews the item an clicks on approve/reject button.

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2: In the below what action should i select so that the manager has the approve/reject button when clicks on the link.
[image]

I was able to do this very easily online but to do some customization in the email content i am using designer but now i am stuck..

Any help?

Comment: I posted the same question here(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/fa0ca108-6452-4f0d-80da-512185b16d68) I hope this isn't against the forum rules

Answer (score 0):

***Addendum***: You may want to edit this message to post the  error message you've provided in the TechNet Forums post

Looks like you're design a workflow that will create an item in the list to which this workflow is attached.

If a user creates an item in that list and automatically starts the workflow, the workflow creates another item, which results in another instance of the workflow. This scenario can cause the workflow to run in a continuous loop.  The error message isn't terribly clear though.

The three potential resolutions to this are: -

1. Use another list in the action that is different from the list attached to the workflow
2. Attach the workflow to a different list
3. On the first page of the Workflow Designer, clear the Automatically start this workflow when a new item is created check box (the second one in your first screenshot), and select the Allow this workflow to be manually started from an item check box (the first one in your first screenshot)